# Using variable in Snowflake COPY INTO command

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, azure-blob-storage

I have a stored procedure which unloads data from table into a Azure blob container. The conditions of file unloading is the file should be unloaded into a date time partition folder.

`2022-06-09/1651011730.067872/FileName.csv`

I have written the following stored procedure:

```
execute immediate 
  $$
    declare
        date_partition varchar;
        date_time_partition varchar;
        
    begin
     
     set date_partition = '2022-06-09';
     set date_time_partition = '1651011730.067872';
     
     COPY INTO @STAGE/:datetime/:date_time_partition/filename 
        FROM (
            select * from table
                where ID = 1
          ) file_format = CSV_FORMAT HEADER = TRUE DETAILED_OUTPUT = TRUE overwrite = true;
    
    return date_partition;
    end;
    
  $$;
```

The problem I am facing is the data is getting on loaded in this format

`date_partition/date_partition/FileName.csv`

What can I do to use the variables in the COPY INTO command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like works for me:

```
execute immediate
$$
declare
  date_partition varchar default '2022-06-09';
  date_time_partition varchar default '1651011730.067872';
  copy_into varchar default 'COPY INTO @~/' || date_partition || '/' || date_time_partition || '/filename FROM (select * from citibike_trips limit 10) file_format = MYCSV HEADER = TRUE DETAILED_OUTPUT = TRUE overwrite = true';
begin
  execute immediate :copy_into;
  return date_partition;
end;
$$;
```

When I list the stage I see:

```
2022-06-09/1651011730.067872/filename_0_0_0.csv.gz
```

Is this what you're looking for?